# How to open a div on tabindex and have it remain open while tabbing through it's content using CSS

Tags: css

I've got a div with some links in it I want users to be able to tab through

```
<a href="#" class="skip-to">show</a>
<div id="skip-to-section-container">
    <a href="[[~[[*id]]]]#skip-to-content">Skip to main content</a>
    <a href="[[~[[*id]]]]#skip-to-navigation">Skip to Navigation</a>
    <a href="[[~[[*id]]]]#skip-to-footer">Skip to Footer</a>
</div>
```

it's for accessibility, so I want the first tabindex to open the div AND have it remain open while the user tabs through the links in it.

here is the CSS:

```
#skip-to-section-container {
    padding: 18px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-161px;
    left:0px;
    color: #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #3AB652;
    border-bottom: 1px solid#3AB652;
    /* border-bottom-right-radius:8px; */
    background: #3AB652;
    z-index:999999;
    }

#skip-to-section-container a {
    color:#fff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    }

a.skip-to {position: absolute; top: -50px;}

a.skip-to:focus + #skip-to-section-container {
    top: 0px;
}
```

So I have 2 problems, it opens fine, but:
- if the user presses tab a second time the .skip-to link loses focus [obviously] and allowing the div to hide again.
- if a user tries to click on one of those links in the div, again the .skip-to loses focus, the div closes and the links are not clickable.

How can I solve this closing div problem?